# React | wait until useEffect is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

EDIT:
Hello guys,

my jsx looks like this

```js
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridValueGetterParams } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getNameOfJSDocTypedef, WatchDirectoryFlags } from '../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript';


// ==============================|| MOB ||============================== //

let first_run = true;




var columns = [];
var rows = [];
const Mob = () => {
  
  const [antDataColumns, setAntDataColumns] = useState([]);
  const urlAntColumns = "QUERYURL";

  const [antData, setAntData] = useState([]);
  const urlAnt = 'QUERYURL';


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(urlAntColumns)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setAntDataColumns(data);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(urlAnt)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setAntData(data);
      });
  }, []);
  if (antDataColumns.length > 0 && antData.length > 0 && first_run === true) {
    columns.push({ field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 })
    for (let i = 6; i < 12; i++){
      columns.push({field: antDataColumns[i]['column_name'], headerName: antDataColumns[i]['column_name'], width: 70});
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      let row = {};
      row["id"] = i+1;
      for (let j = 1; j < columns.length; j++) {
        row[columns[j]['field']] = antData[i][columns[j]['field']];
      }
      rows.push(row);
    }
    first_run = false;
    }
    console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    console.log(columns)
    
    

    console.log("---")


    console.log(rows)
    

    console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 1000, width: '100%' }}>
  <DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={10}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
    checkboxSelection
  />
</div>
    )

    
};

export default Mob;
```

The table does not show up. But the data is loaded after a few seconds... I don't understand why shows nothing. Im using MATERIAL UI. Data Grid.
The 'columns' and 'rows' look like this
[image]

But I get a error and not output. Maybe because fetch is not finished when the website is rendering...

Thats the error
[image]

Comment: *"this only works if the variables are already defined"* - How are those two pieces of code even related?  The state being defined/updated in the first code snippet isn't used in the second, and the variables used in the second aren't defined in the first.  How is rendering a component related to logging a value to the console?

Comment: *"But I get a error"* - What's the error?  With each edit of the question you seem to be trying very hard to *avoid* asking about the actual problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: @David I remove the old code. Sorry, for that. I  just forgot to edit that part too.

Comment: That error is pointing you to a specific line of code or specific operation.  Which operation is producing that error?  When the error occurs (when you debug), what are the runtime values used in that operation?  (Also note that it's *very strange* and probably *very wrong* to be using these module-level `columns` and `rows` variables like this.  Why aren't they in the component?)

Comment: Im a beginner so sorry for these questions... what do you mean with component? I load these from a database.

Comment: "Component" is a fairly important term in React development.  In the code shown you are defining a component called `Mob`.  This component renders a component called `DataGrid`.  Overall, the problem is ***probably*** in all that complex logic between your `useEffect` calls and your `return`, all of which you seem to be glossing over and for some reason focusing on `useEffect` as the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250235/discussion-between-codeode-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the component from rendering its content, based on a condition from your state.

```
  const [antDataColumns, setAntDataColumns] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, []);

if (!antDataColumns.length) return null;

console.log("X")
```

Or you can create a second state : a loading state, that is true while the request is processed and false when it is finished.

Comment: I updated the question, can you please have a look at it?